# Open a raster in HDFS using GDAL

Tags: hdfs, gdal

I read in GDAL documentation that starting 2.4 it is possible to open a raster in HDFS. I downloaded and compiled the latest source code available version and the generated libraries show it is 2.4 (libgdal.so.20.4.2). I compiled with option "-with-hdfs=yes" and "--with-java=yes".

I am trying to open a raster using:
    Dataset raster = gdal.Open("/vsihdfs/hdfs://node:8020/user/hdfs   /spatial_raster/input_raster/kahoolawe.tif", gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly);

but I am getting the  following error: "ERROR 4: No such file or directory"

could anyone please tell me if hdfs virtual system not supported yet?, or maybe I configured it wrong when compiling?

Appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Important are environment variables `JAVA_HOME` and `HADOOP_HOME`.

Export `CLASSPATH=$($HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop classpath --glob)`

I hope this can help you :

1. https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1333
2. https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/714